# How to solve these recurrences

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have this recurrence and I have tried to solve it but I am completely lost. Master Theorem cannot be applied on this at-least not without some substitution or stuff.

$ i)\quad T(n) = 4 T( \left \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\right \rfloor + 5) + n^2$

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** Since I am already asking one question, I would put another recurrence in here as well. It seems really complicated and I am not sure which method should I be applying to solve it.

$ii) \quad T(n) = T(n-4) + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{5}{n^2+6} + \frac{7n^2}{3n^2+8} $

Comment: It looks like you omitted a closed parenthesis somewhere.

Comment: Its fixed now, sorry about that